# Find the Wronskian of the Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, determinant, wronskian

Find the Wronskian of the functions $f(t)=6e^t\sin{t}$ and $g(t)=e^t\cos(t)$. Simplify your answer.
please list out all steps as simple as possible
thank you

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $W(f,g)=\det \left(\begin{bmatrix}f & g\\ f' & g' \end{bmatrix}\right)$

Comment: You need to list out the steps you've taken and state what your difficulty is. And ask nicely, don't demand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall, that given $$f(t)=6e^t\sin{t}\quad g(t)=e^t\cos(t)$$

The Wronskian of $f(t), g(t) = W(f,g)(t)$

$$W(f, g)(t) =\det \left(\begin{bmatrix}f(t) & g(t) \\ f'(t) & g'(t) \end{bmatrix}\right)$$

So find  each of $f'(t)$ and $g'(t)$, and substitute $f, g, f', g'$ into the matrix; then you simply compute the determinant: $$W(f, g)(t)= f(t)\cdot g'(t) - f'(t)\cdot g(t)$$